# kafka broker's replication out of syn cause no message received

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a cluster of 3 brokers(id : 0,1,2).  version:0.8.1 
We restart(simply use stop.sh and start.sh in bin directory) broker 1. The broker started successfully. However, all the partitions' leader moved to other brokers
and no data were written into broker 2. It seems the replication in broker 1 is 'out of syn', because broker 1 is not in topic's Isr. As a result, the leader would not forward the message to this broker.
In this case, how should i synchronize all the replications?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to ivestigate through this document:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools#Replicationtools-2.PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionTool

it may be helpful